# Manipulação de arquivo .txt

Tags: php

Eu tenho uma página em php chamada "emblema.php", e um arquivo .txt chamado "emblema.txt". Neste arquivo .txt, é onde eu coloco título, código e descrição do emblema.

O código é assim:

```
badge_name_CÓDIGO DO EMBLEMA=NOME DO EMBLEMA (TITULO DO EMBLEMA)
badge_desc_CÓDIGO DO EMBLEMA=DESCRIÇÃO DO EMBLEMA
```

E eu queria saber se dava para eu criar isso sem ser manualmente.Obviamente, para adicionar um emblema, eu preciso duplicar este conteúdo e mudar o código, título e descrição.

Eu queria fazer com que fosse adicionado assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sim, é possível. Veja as funções `fopen`, `file_put_contents`, `fread`, `fwrite` (as mesmas da linguagem C). Elas vão te ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função `file_put_contents` para manipular um arquivo.

## Criando um arquivo TXT

O `file_put_contents` pode ser utilizado para criar um arquivo com um determinado conteúdo.

Exemplo:

```
$filename = __DIR__ . '/arquivos/log.txt';

file_put_contents($filename, 'meu conteúdo');
```

O exemplo acima fará com que seja criado o arquivo `log.txt` dentro da pasta `arquivos` do diretório atual do seu script, definido pela constante mágica `__DIR__`.

Porém, nesse exemplo, o arquivo será sobrescrito caso ele exista. E, a cada nova requisição, sempre mudará o conteúdo.

## Adicionando dados ao final de um arquivo TXT

Se você quer sempre quer adicionar um novo conteúdo no final do arquivo, você poderá utilizar a flag `FILE_APPEND` como parâmetro de `file_put_contents`.

Assim:

```
file_put_contents($filename, 'meu conteúdo', FILE_APPEND);
```

Isso sempre criará um novo conteúdo ao final do arquivo.

## Por que não usar CSV?

Como no seu exemplo me parece que você está trabalhando com dados com estruturas organizadas específicas, eu utilizaria um CSV.

O PHP manipula muito bem o CSV.

Dê uma olhada nessas explicações do Manual do PHP:

[fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fgetcsv.php)

[fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fputcsv.php)

## serialização de dados

A partir das funções `serialize` e `unserialize` do PHP é possível "salvar" valores de variáveis para, mais tarde, recuperá-los. Tudo que você precisa é de um arquivo onde salvar esses dados.

Veja um exemplo.

Salvando os dados:

```
$serial = serialize($_POST);
file_put_contents('serial.txt', $serial);
```

Recuperando os dados:

```
$dados = unserialize(file_get_contents('serial.txt'));
print_r($dados); // Dados anterioremente salvos vindos de $_POST
```

Parece-me que internamente o PHP utilize essas funções para salvar/recuperar os dados da sessão (`$_SESSION`).

Comment: Eu não uso o CSV, pois o sistema terá de ser mudado completamente. E tipo, como faço para que a base seja feita e o código, título e descrição sejam multiplicados conforme vai criando os outros?

Comment: Você quer criar mais de um arquivo? OU quer sempre adicionar dados ao final desse arquivo?

Comment: @Train não entendi o porque não usar o CSV, para que inventar um novo tipo de documento, sendo que existe um (o CSV) que pode ser facilmente manipulado. Ao meu ver não precisa mudar nada na resposta, é só uma escolha de formato, você não definiu que tipo de formato você quer na questão, então ao meu ver CSV é totalmente funcional para o seu caso :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters A melhor situação é a *serialização de dados*, porém isto `file_put_contents('serial.txt', $serial);` não dividiria por `ID`, o melhor seria cada TXT ser um ID (código do emblema) ou você fornecer um exemplo que trabalhe com quebra de linha e usar `fgets`+`foef`+`while` :) Só uma ideia.

Comment: `file_get_contents` é a simplificação de `fgests` + `foef` + `while`. Não há por que usá-los como exemplo. Vou elaborar uma forma de fazer toda essa operação com o `file_get_contents` e `serialize`.